# How to add a page refresh feature after a TTS message is read

Tags: javascript, electron, text-to-speech

I am trying to add a page refresh to my application after my TTS has finished talking. It should be simple enough, I just don't know TTS that well. Right now I have a Keyup that starts the sequence of TTS talking, then another Keyup that refreshes the page. But I want the refresh to occur directly after the speech finishes too.

I have tried this:

```
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
window.location.reload();
```

Which obviously just reloads as the text starts talking. I have also thought about doing something like this:

```
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg).window.location.reload();
```

But that does not seem right. I am sure it's probably close to that. Note:Below is not my complete code due to confidentiality.

```
var voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
speechSynthesis.getVoices().forEach(function(voice) {
  console.log(voice.name, voice.default ? voice.default
    :
    '');
});

msg.pitch = 1.1;
msg.volume = 1;
msg.rate = 0.65;
msg.voice = voices[5];
msg.lang = 'en-US';


window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
window.location.reload();


document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 82)
    window.location.reload();
})
```

I just want to reload AFTER the message is spoken

Answer (score 2):

You can attach a function to the `onend` event of your message that is spoken.

Here is a bare bones example that plays a message, and then reloads a page.

```
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
msg.text = "Hello there";
msg.onend = function(what) { console.log('event details',what); window.location.reload(); }
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

Comment: Thank you Kyle K, I tried using this but it does not work as my TTS is reading from a tabulated list so after it reads the first line, msg.onend will reload my page and interrupt this. Do you know if there's a way around that?

Comment: You'd want to attach the `onend` event on the last line.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code to page refresh

```
location.reload();
```

or

```
location.reload(true);
```

or

```
window.location.reload();
```

or

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

or

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

or

```
setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(); }, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks but how would I incorporate that into refreshing after the speech?

Comment: but I do have window.location.reload(); how do I correctly place that to make it automatic?